# package.json inside react-native folder

Tags: react-native

I downloaded a react-native application from a git repository.  Inside it, there is a file called package.json that looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^27.0.0",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "link:../..",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^0.0.4",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "0.1.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^0.5.1"
  }
```

Do I need to use npm to install all these libraries or will the app download them automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `npm install`, it will automatically download all libraries/package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to `npm install` in the terminal, from the project root directory, to download and install the dependencies, as @gaback suggested in a comment.

Alternatively, if you prefer using yarn, you can `yarn install` from the same directory to install the dependencies.